# Cocoa/Swift: Loop through names of folder in path

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsfilemanager

I'm currently programming an os x application with swift, but I can't figure how to loop through or even get the names of all folders at a certain path. Maybe something with `fm.enumeratorAtPath`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `enumeratorAtURL`. Here's some code that shows an example of how to print the directories in the user's home directory.

```
if let dirURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()) {
    let keys = [NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLLocalizedNameKey]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let enumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(
        dirURL,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: keys,
        options: (NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsPackageDescendants |
            NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants |
            NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles),
        errorHandler: {(url, error) -> Bool in
            return true
        }
    )
    while let element = enumerator?.nextObject() as? NSURL {
        var getter: AnyObject?
        element.getResourceValue(&getter, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey, error: nil)
        let isDirectory = getter! as Bool
        element.getResourceValue(&getter, forKey: NSURLLocalizedNameKey, error: nil)
        let itemName = getter! as String
        if isDirectory {
            println("\(itemName) is a directory in \(dirURL.absoluteString)")
            //do something with element here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly should give the general idea. However, it does not compile in Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I fixed the compile errors and tried it in a playground. It compiles and works now.